# How do I compare and order two arraylists in Java

Tags: java

I am getting input from two files on my hard drive:

studentNames.txt and studentScores.txt - the names have the student ID and name while the scores has the student ID and scores. I have put the data into two ArrayLists and want to sort the data so that the grades go to the matching ID.

For example:

```
+------+--------------+---------+
|  ID  |     Name     |  Grade  |
+------+--------------+---------+
| 3305 | Smith Henry  | 92.0    |
| 5555 | Eddy Olivia  | 95.5    |
| 8915 | Johnson Luke | 98.5    |
+------+--------------+---------+
```

And the data continues to populate with just the ID / Grade - I know I need to use an if statement, but how would I go about doing that?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class P_Supplemental_9 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   File file1 = new File("c:/temp/studentNames.txt");
   File file2 = new File("c:/temp/studentScores.txt");

   if(file1.exists()) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(file1);

   ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList();

   while(input.hasNext()) {
   students.add(new Student(input.nextInt(),input.nextLine()));
   }

   input.close();

   for(int o = 0;o < students.size();o++) {
   System.out.printf("%10d %20s avg\n", students.get(o).getStuId(),     students.get(o).getStuName());

   } // end for

   }

   if(file2.exists()) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(file2);

       ArrayList<Student> grades = new ArrayList();

       while(input.hasNext()) {
           grades.add(new Student(input.nextInt(), input.nextLine()));

       } /// end while
       input.close();

   for(int o = 0;o < grades.size();o++) {

       System.out.printf("%10d %20s avg\n", grades.get(o).getStuId(), grades.get(o).getStuName());
   } // end for

   } // end if(file2.exists)





  } // end main method
 } // end P_Supplemental_9



class Student {
    private int stuId;
    private String stuName;
    private ArrayList <Double> grades;

    Student(int idIn, String nameIn) {

        this.stuId = idIn;
        this.stuName = nameIn;
       } // end student class

    Student(int idIn, ArrayList gradesIn) {
        this.stuId = idIn;
        this.grades = gradesIn;

    }

        public int getStuId() {
            return stuId;
        }

        /**
         * @param stuId the stuId to set
         */
        public void setStuId(int stuId) {
            this.stuId = stuId;
        }

        /**
         * @return the stuName
         */
        public String getStuName() {
            return stuName;
        }

        /**
         * @param stuName the stuName to set
         */
        public void setStuName(String stuName) {
            this.stuName = stuName;
        }

        /**
         * @return the grades
         */
        public ArrayList getGrades() {
            return grades;
        }

        /**
         * @param grades the grades to set
         */
        public void setGrades(ArrayList grades) {
            this.grades = grades;
        }

} // end student class
```

Heres the data from Studentnames.txt

```
3305 Smith Henry
5555 Eddy Olivia
8915 Johnson Luke
```

Heres the data from Studentscores.txt

```
3305 92.0
5555 95.5
8915 98.5
3305 89.0
5555 90.5
8915 95.5
3305 78.5
5555 85.0
8915 82.0
```

Comment: you should make it clearer. Why kind of "object" does this arraylist contain ?

Comment: @hqt would you like me to post my code?

Comment: @user1717964 Yes, in particular the structure of the data

Comment: Having actual examples of your two input files would also be helpful. Often, there's a better way to solve a problem by starting from scratch in a different way.

Comment: @hqt included the whole file including the two data files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Collections#sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort the two lists.

Assuming that their is a one to one relationship between the students and their scores, this will allow you to get the student and score and each element of the list.

I would imagine it looking something like this.

```
Collections.sort(studentNames, new Comparator<Student>() {
    public int compareTo(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.getStuId() - o2.getStuId();
    }
});
```

This will provide you with a `List` of students ordered by their student ID.

You would then use the same concept to order the scores list.  Once you have that, the two lists should now be in student id order and you should be able to loop over them.

Another idea would be to store the students and scores in a `Map` keyed to the student ID.

You would then be able to iterate the map's keys and pull out each student and score based on those IDs

**UPDATED to meet requirements**

After reading the updated requirements, I've noted that it would be better to use a sorted map rather the a list.

Basically, we place each student name into a sorted map keyed against the individual IDs.  We then place each on a list within a sorted map keyed against the IDs

```
public class TestArraySort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestArraySort();
    }

    public TestArraySort() {

        try {
            File file1 = new File("studentNames.txt");
            File file2 = new File("studentScores.txt");

            // Better to check for both files here, other wise it's just wasting time
            if (file1.exists() && file2.exists()) {
                // Create the sorted maps so that they are in scope...
                Map<Integer, String> mapStudents = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
                Map<Integer, List<Double>> mapScores = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Double>>();

                Scanner input = null;
                try {
                    input = new Scanner(file1);
                    // Read the student information...
                    while (input.hasNext()) {
                        int id = input.nextInt();
                        String name = input.nextLine().trim();
                        mapStudents.put(id, name);
                    }
                    // Safty net
                } finally {
                    input.close();
                }

                try {
                    // Read the scores
                    input = new Scanner(file2);
                    while (input.hasNext()) {
                        int id = input.nextInt();
                        double score = input.nextDouble();

                        // If the list doesn't already exist, create it
                        List<Double> scores = mapScores.get(id);
                        if (scores == null) {
                            scores = new ArrayList<Double>(25);
                            mapScores.put(id, scores);
                        }
                        scores.add(score);
                    } /// end while
                    // Safty net
                } finally {
                    input.close();
                }

                // Dump the results
                System.out.println("+------------+----------------------+------+");
                for (Integer id : mapStudents.keySet()) {
                    // Display the student results
                    String name = mapStudents.get(id);
                    System.out.printf("| %10d | %-20s | ", id, name);
                    List<Double> scores = mapScores.get(id);
                    if (scores.size() > 0) {

                        // Sort the list
                        Collections.sort(scores);
                        // Reverse the list so that the scores are now in order from highest to lowest
                        // Sure, I could create a reverse comparator when I sort it, but
                        // I'm lazy...
                        Collections.reverse(scores);

                        // Print the first score...
                        System.out.printf("%4.1f |\n", scores.get(0));
                        // Print the remaining scores...
                        for (int index = 1; index < scores.size(); index++) {
                            System.out.printf("| %10s | %-20s | %4.1f |\n", "", "", scores.get(index));
                        }

                    } else {

                        System.out.println("00.0 |");

                    }
                    System.out.println("+------------+----------------------+------+");

                }

            } // end if(file2.exists)    }

        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces

```
+------------+----------------------+------+
|       3305 | Smith Henry          | 92.0 |
|            |                      | 89.0 |
|            |                      | 78.5 |
+------------+----------------------+------+
|       5555 | Eddy Olivia          | 95.5 |
|            |                      | 90.5 |
|            |                      | 85.0 |
+------------+----------------------+------+
|       8915 | Johnson Luke         | 98.5 |
|            |                      | 95.5 |
|            |                      | 82.0 |
+------------+----------------------+------+
```

Comment: I prefer you didn't :P - If you can, update your question with the relevant part of the code (the loading of the students and scores) and some sample data from each file

Comment: I edited it to show my main method. I have a class underneath but I think you'll get the jist

Comment: You have repeating groups (that is, each student has 1 or more scores) do you want those averaged or sorted as well...?

Comment: Yes...So, theres three students in the class each with multiple grades. I want the ID to match the name and the grades to match the ID

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to compare two values from different arrayLists, assuming they are string values

`if (array1.get(i).toString().compareTo(array2.get(j).toString()) == 0`)

Comment: I have three separate values: int, double and string. The int is the students id, the double is the student's grade and the string is the name... I esentially need to match the multiple grades with the multiple ID's

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach, both in terms of efficiency and ease of writing, would be to use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). As you read either file, map the student IDs to the data associated with it (either name or test score). Then, traverse the set of student ID's, obtaining the name and score with `nameMap.get(id)` and `scoreMap.get(id)`, respectively - where each `id` is an element of the set of IDs, obtainable with `nameMap.keySet()`.

Comment: We haven't used Map yet - not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your `class`. Now you can easily call `Collections.sort(studentNames)` (assuming `studentNames` is a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html))

Answer (score 0):

```
File one data
abc
abcd
bcd

file two data
abc
abcd 
bcd
cdf


final resutlt

abc
abc 
abcd
abcd
bcd
bcd
cdf



package com.ravisoft.logic;
/*
String tempDataArray[] =
    StringUtils.split(mergeStr, Utils.LINE_SEPARATOR);
java.util.Arrays.sort(tempDataArray);

String data = StringUtils.join(tempDataArray, Utils.LINE_SEPARATOR, 0);*/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> fileData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String fileName1 = "E:\\ROUTINE_WORK\\MAY_ROUTINE_WORK\\MAY282013\\New1.TXT";
        String fileName2 = "E:\\ROUTINE_WORK\\MAY_ROUTINE_WORK\\MAY282013\\New2.TXT";
        int lines = 0;
        try 
        {
          // set up input stream1
        FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(fileName1);
          // buffer the input stream
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);

          // set up input stream2
        FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(fileName2);
          // buffer the input stream
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);

          // read and display1
        String buffer1 = "";



        while ((buffer1 = br1.readLine()) != null)
        {
          fileData.add(buffer1);

          System.out.println("First file: "+buffer1);  // display the line
          ++lines;
        }

      br1.close();

        String buffer2 = "";


            while ((buffer2 = br2.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                  fileData.add(buffer2);

                  System.out.println("Second file: "+buffer2);  // display the line
                  ++lines;
            }

      br2.close();
    System.out.println("Total lines before sorting: "+lines);
    lines=0;
      Collections.sort(fileData);


      System.out.println("Sorted list");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();

        for(String s : fileData) {
            ++lines;
          System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println("Total lines after sort: "+lines);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

}
```